# Disable notifications for random news stories

Tags: notifications, 9.0-pie

Many times per day, my phone shows me notifications like the one below. It's a random news story (which admittedly is on a topic I am interested in), but I have never wanted to get a *notification* about a news story, ever.

I hate it displaying a new news story every 10 minutes, but I'm fine with it giving a notification for things like the weather, my commute, etc., so I'd rather not disable all Google notifications. I'm also fine with it listing these news stories in the leftmost page of the home screen, I just don't need a notification about them. (I'm also fine with losing the news stories from the leftmost page, if that's the only way to get rid of the notifications.)

I have tried this already: From the leftmost page of the home screen, click the user account icon in the upper-right, select 'Settings', select 'Notifications'. I disabled several categories, including 'Topics of interest', 'Business listings', and 'Stocks'. There is no 'news' category or similar.

I do see the option to remove a particular news source (e.g., 'InsideEVs' in the screenshot below), but that's not a solution; I want all of them gone at once, not whack-a-mole.

My phone is a Pixel 3 XL, running Android 9.

Here's an example of a notification I want to get rid of.
[image]

Comment: The message in the screenshot looks to me like a "**Stocks**" notification of Google Now: https://www.maketecheasier.com/control-google-now-notifications/

Comment: "Stocks" is one of the notification categories I already had disabled. (The two I listed in the question were not a complete list, just the two that seemed most likely to me.)